# protovis magical properties

Tags: scope, javascript, protovis

I am pretty new to protovis. I was trying to understand the example in http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/docs/panel.html I can understand `left(function() this.index * 10)`is actually `left(function(){return this.index * 10;})`  and when the function is called a scope is passed to it thats `this` well and fine till now. BUt `data(function(array) array)` doesn't takes the array from `this`. rather its passed to it. from where this `array` is passed ? I cannot understand the flow of the chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the many parts of Protovis that's a bit confusing at first. When you add data to a mark, e.g.:

```
var mark = new pv.Panel()
    .data([1,2,3]);
```

the mark will be duplicated once for each item in the `data` array, and passed the corresponding item as the first argument to its functions, e.g.:

```
new pv.Panel()
    .data([1,2,3])
    .title(function(d) { // <-- d is 1, 2, or 3
        return d;
    });
```

Any child mark you attach to `mark` will also receive this data point, which can then be used by the child mark as the input argument for *its* functions, e.g.:

```
new pv.Panel()
    .data([1,2,3])
  .add(pv.Label)
    .text(function(d) { // <-- d is 1, 2, or 3
        return d;
    });
```

But child marks can also define their own `data()`, which will duplicate that mark accordingly. A child mark's data can be totally independent, e.g.:

```
new pv.Panel()
    .data([1,2,3])
  .add(pv.Label)
    .data([3,4,5])
    .text(function(d) { // <-- d is 3, 4, or 5
        return d;
    });
```

But often, as in the example you link to, the parent will have a 2- or 3-d array as its data, and the child will base its `data()` on the sub-array it's passed:

```
new pv.Panel()
    .data([[1,2,3], [3,4,5]])
  .add(pv.Label)
    .data(function(d) { // <-- d is [1,2,3] or [3,4,5]
        return d;
    })
    .text(function(d) { // <-- d is either 1, 2, or 3, 
                        // OR 3, 4, or 5
        return d;
    });
```